# JavaScript KeyCode Values are "undefined" in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I'm having trouble with some JavaScript that I've written, but only with Internet Explorer 8. I have no problem executing this on Internet Explorer 7 or earlier or on Mozilla Firefox 3.5 or earlier. It also executes properly when I use compatibility mode on Internet Explorer 8.

What I'm doing is overriding the Enter keystroke when a user enters a value into a textbox. So on my element I have this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ddPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" onkeypress="doSubmit(event)" Width="325"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then I have the following JavaScript method:

```
function doSubmit(e)
{
    var keyCode = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13)
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login").click();  
}
```

Again, this all works fine with almost every other browser. Internet Explorer 8 is just giving me a hard time.

Any help you might have is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for your quick feedback. Both Chris Pebble and Bryan Kyle assisted with this solution. I have awarded Bryan the "answer" to help with his reputation. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like under IE8 the `keyCode` property of `window.Event` is `undefined` but that same property of `window.event` (note the lowercase **e**) has the value.  You might try using `window.event`.

```
function doSubmit(e)
{
   var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
   if (keyCode == 13)
      document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login").click();  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just a hunch, try this:

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
```

Comment: This worked on Internet Explorer 8, but did not work on any of the other browsers that this code used to work on.

Comment: Chris, please see my commenting below. You assitance along with Bryan's helped solve this! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It's worked on this way on my code:

```
var kcode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function checkKeyCode(e){  
    if (!e) e = window.event;   var kCd =  e.which ||  e.keyCode;
    return kCd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the multi-key approach. This allows multiple keys to be detected, but also a single key just the same, and it works in every browser I've tested.

```
map={}//declare object to hold data
onkeydown=onkeyup=function(e){
    e=e||event//if e doesn't exist (like in IE), replace it with window.event
    map[e.keyCode]=e.type=='keydown'?true:false
    //Check for keycodes
}
```

An alternative method would be to separate the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events and explicitly define the map subitems in each event:

```
map={}
onkeydown=function(e){
    e=e||event
    map[e.keyCode]=true
}
onkeyup=function(e){
    e=e||event
    map[e.keyCode]=false
}
```

Either way works fine. Now, to actually detect keystrokes, the method, including bug fixes, is:

```
//[in onkeydown or onkeyup function, after map[e.keyCode] has been decided...]
if(map[keycode]){
    //do something
    map={}
    return false
}
```

`map[keycode]` constitutes a specific keycode, like `13` for `Enter`, or `17` for `CTRL`.

The `map={}` line clears the map object to keep it from "holding" onto keys in cases of unfocusing, while `return false` prevents, for example, the Bookmarks dialog from popping up when you check for `CTRL+D`. In some cases, you might want to replace it with `e.preventDefault()`, but I've found `return false` to be more efficient in most cases. Just to get a clear perspective, try it with `CTRL+D`. `Ctrl` is `17`, and `D` is `68`. Notice that without the `return false` line, the Bookmarks dialog will pop up.

Some examples follow:

```
if(map[17]&&map[13]){//CTRL+ENTER
    alert('CTRL+ENTER was pressed')
    map={}
    return false
}else if(map[13]){//ENTER
    alert('Enter was pressed')
    map={}
    return false
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that smaller combinations should come last. Always put larger combinations first in the if..else chain, so you don't get an alert for both `Enter` and `CTRL+ENTER` at the same time.

Now, a full example to "put it all together". Say you want to alert a message that contains instructions for logging in when the user presses `SHIFT+?` and log in when the user presses `ENTER`. This example is also cross-browser compatible, meaning it works in IE, too:

```
map={}
keydown=function(e){
    e=e||event
    map[e.keyCode]=true
    if(map[16]&&map[191]){//SHIFT+?
        alert('1) Type your username and password\n\n2) Hit Enter to log in')
        map={}
        return false
    }else if(map[13]){//Enter
        alert('Logging in...')
        map={}
        return false
    }
}
keyup=function(e){
    e=e||event
    map[e.keyCode]=false
}
onkeydown=keydown
onkeyup=keyup//For Regular browsers
try{//for IE
    document.attachEvent('onkeydown',keydown)
    document.attachEvent('onkeyup',keyup)
}catch(e){
    //do nothing
}
```

Note that some special keys have different codes for different engines. But as I've tested, this works in every browser I currently have on my computer, including Maxthon 3, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer (9 and 8), and Firefox.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding onkeyup event as well and call the same function.

TIP:
You can add `debugger;` at beginning of doSubmit to set a break, then you can examine keyCode.

Comment: Interesting, the "onkeyup" event doesn't even execute in this case on Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.Event.keyCode` works in IE8 (I can't test right now though)

Answer (score 0):

Or something like that.
var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;