# Unable to get value of property 'keyCode': object is null or undefined : Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

One of the customers are facing difficulty while logging into our webiste, whenever the user types the first character in UserName text box on the sign in page, he gets below JavaScript error message.

Unable to get value of property 'keyCode': object is null or undefined

We do check for event.keyCode to validate the userName textbox , so as soon as the user types the first character we send the event.keyCode for validation which is failing.

The browser is internet Explorer 9 and we are not able to reproduce the problem in our workstation which has I9

Comment: Try with ``e.which``. Also [take a look at this thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750223/javascript-keycode-values-are-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: In IE9 event handling depends on how you assign your handlers. Please post a code snippet of your handler-function and the code assigning the handler.

Comment: As the problem was not reproducible On another workstation having IE 9 , I asked the customer for clearing the cache of the browser , this has fixed the problem.. I will check whether again some user faces the same problem.Thanks for help.