# document.onkeypress = function ( event ) IE8 support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

So far  works great in Firefox but not IE. I have to get working both. Any help/ideas appreciated.

```
document.onkeypress = function ( event ) {
var e = event.target.tagName || event.srcElement.tagName;
var k = event.keyCode;
if ( e == 'INPUT' && k == 13 )
$('#get-rate').click();
```

Comment: This question may help: [JavaScript KeyCode Values are “undefined” in Internet Explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750223/javascript-keycode-values-are-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: It appears you are using jQuery here; why not use it for the event handler as well?