# Use .bind method for down arrow key

Tags: javascript

I successfully enabled this alert to show whenever I scrolled down with my mouse in the `<div>`

```
$('#divID').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0) 
    {
        alert('scroll down with scroll');
    }
});
```

What is the equivalent .bind method I can use to alert whenever I scrolled down with my down arrow key in the `<div>`

My attempt is (but doesn't work):

```
$('#section1').bind('onkeydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        alert('scroll down with arrow key');
    }
});
```

I'd highly appreciate any help.

I've checked out a solution from: [JavaScript KeyCode Values are "undefined" in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750223/javascript-keycode-values-are-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8)
 - However with this, I can't seem to have this alert happen for a specific `<div>`, I don't want this effect lingering throughout the whole document.

I am also using `.bind()` and not any other method, it's because when I get to another `<div>` I want to `.unbind()` the previous, because in another `<div>` I want to do a new `.bind()`

Comment: Have you just tried the [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/scroll)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm doing it right, would it be replacing the 'onkeydown' with 'scroll'?? Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: No, `scroll` is for all scrolls; I don't think there is a special event for scrolling by keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Henry i the problem is **

> **'onkeydown'**
>
> above keyword is the html tag's event attribute
>
> you can check out the below reference link for this
>   [**Reference link 'onkeydown' keyword**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeydown.asp)

key word that you have used to bind the key down that's actually only

> **'keydown'**

that's the only problem else you code is proper

and here is my try with that code.

```js
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 40) {
                
                alert("down pressed");
            } else if (code == 38) {
                alert("up pressed");
            }
        });
```

and here is the link for working code you can check out

[**Working code**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9uDn/140/)

[**Even working here with .bind() event to you can check out code**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9uDn/141/)

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but if I do $(document).unbind('keydown'); would that work?

Comment: And if I do this: $(document).bind('keydown', kd(e)); where

Comment: function kd(e) {
                    var activeSection = $('.pp-section.active').index('.pp-section');
                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (code == 40 && activeSection == 1) {
                        //PP.moveTo('page1');
                        alert('down');
                    }
                    if (code == 39 && activeSection == 1) {
                        //PP.moveTo('page1');
                        alert('down');
                    }
                }

Comment: @Henry it's just use of $(document) to give an example you can write selector as on which you want to bind the keydown event

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Henry welcome buddy  if this helped you then you can just up vote it.

Comment: My reputation hasn't attained 15 yet, but I posted another similar question so maybe if you can some reputation points there, I can help you upvote this one. Help each other, you know what I'm saying

Comment: Here's my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648080/if-condition-in-javascript-doesnt-seem-to-obey-as-coded?noredirect=1#comment58977008_35648080

Comment: Please have a look Himesh