# if condition in Javascript doesn't seem to obey as coded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I get to the opening < div1 > section, the down arrow key doesn't let me go to the next < div2 > section unless the button in < div1 > section is pressed and I have 4 < div > sections which replicate this effect. This is no problem.

My problem is for example: when I get to < div2 > section, when I press the up arrow key and get to < div1 > section, and then press the down arrow key, it will not let me go down to < div2 > section, because my plan was that by pressing the button in < div1 > section, it should lift any restriction applied to the down arrow key for < div1 > section. I plan on replicating this for all the other 3 < div > sections.

I am using JQuery and a Parallax Scrolling Plugin called PagePiling, I believe that my problem is not specifically related to PagePiling, even though PagePiling uses < div > sections to create these Parallax Scrolling effects.

If you run my code, I wrote what my problem is with the code in between < p > and < /p >. The problem should lie in the setup() method. Anyway I'll let you try it and you'll see what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/master/jquery.pagepiling.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/master/jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                /* Plugin intialization */
                $('#example').pagepiling({
                    menu: '#menu',
                    anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
                    sectionsColor: ['white', '#ee005a', 'white', '#39C'],
                    navigation: {
                        'position': 'right',
                        'tooltips': ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4']
                    },
                    afterRender: function () {
                        $('#pp-nav').addClass('custom');
                    },
                    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
                        if (index > 1) {
                            $('#pp-nav').removeClass('custom');
                        } else {
                            $('#pp-nav').addClass('custom');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#f1").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $("#f2").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $("#f3").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                url = window.location;
                var PP = $.fn.pagepiling;

                function setup() {
                    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                        var activeSection = $('.pp-section.active').index('.pp-section');
                        var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
                        if (keyCode == 40 && activeSection == 1) {
                            PP.moveTo('page1');
                        }
                        if (keyCode == 39 && activeSection == 1) {
                            PP.moveTo('page1');
                        }
                        if (keyCode == 40 && activeSection == 2) {
                            PP.moveTo('page2');
                        }
                        if (keyCode == 39 && activeSection == 2) {
                            PP.moveTo('page2');
                        }
                        if (keyCode == 40 && activeSection == 3) {
                            PP.moveTo('page3');
                        }
                        if (keyCode == 39 && activeSection == 3) {
                            PP.moveTo('page3');
                        }
                    });
                }
                setup();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            /* Custom CSS
             * --------------------------------------- */
            body,div,ul,li,h1,form,button,p {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                pading: 0;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 4em;
            }
            .section {
                text-align: center;
            }

            /* Menu
             * --------------------------------------- */
            #menu li {
                display:inline-block;
                margin: 10px;
                color: #000;
                background:#fff;
                background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            #menu li.active{
                background:#666;
                background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
                color: #fff;
            }
            #menu li a{
                text-decoration:none;
                color: #000;
            }
            #menu li.active a:hover{
                color: #000;
            }
            #menu li:hover{
                background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
            }
            #menu li a,
            #menu li.active a{
                padding: 9px 18px;
                display:block;
            }
            #menu li.active a{
                color: #fff;
            }
            #menu{
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                height: 40px;
                z-index: 70;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin:0;
            }

            /* Overwriting fullPage.js tooltip color
            * --------------------------------------- */
            #pp-nav.custom .pp-tooltip{
                color: #AAA;
            }
            #markup{
                display: block;
                width: 450px;
                margin: 20px auto;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li data-menuanchor="page1" class="active"><a href="#page1">Page1</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="page2"><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="page3"><a href="#page3">Page3</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="page4"><a href="#page4">Page4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="example">
            <div class="section" id="section1">
                <h1>Page 1</h1>
                <p>Initially, the down arrow key will stop you from proceeding to Page 2, unless you press the button. <br><br></p>
                <button id="f1" onclick="return s2()">Click me to proceed</button>
                <p><br>However if you are on Page 2, when you return to Page 1, the down arrow key still stops you from proceeding to Page 2. <br>Here is where my problem is, it shouldn't be preventing you from going to Page 2</p>
                <p><br>(I know you can scroll downwards as well as use the navigation button at the top and on your right side <br>but for the purposes here, I only need to solve this)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section2">
                <h1>Page 2</h1>
                <p>Initially, the down arrow key will stop you from proceeding to Page 3, unless you press the button. <br><br></p>
                <button id="f2" onclick="return s3()">Click me to proceed</button>
                <p><br>However if you are on Page 3, when you return to Page 2, the down arrow key still stops you from proceeding to Page 3. <br>Here is where my problem is, it shouldn't be preventing you from going to Page 3</p>
                <p><br>(I know you can scroll downwards as well as use the navigation button at the top and on your right side <br>but for the purposes here, I only need to solve this)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section3">
                <h1>Page 3</h1>
                <p>Initially, the down arrow key will stop you from proceeding to Page 4, unless you press the button. <br><br></p>
                <button id="f3" onclick="return s4()">Click me to proceed</button>
                <p><br>However if you are on Page 4, when you return to Page 3, the down arrow key still stops you from proceeding to Page 4. <br>Here is where my problem is, it shouldn't be preventing you from going to Page 4</p>
                <p><br>(I know you can scroll downwards as well as use the navigation button at the top and on your right side <br>but for the purposes here, I only need to solve this)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section4">
                <h1>Page 4</h1>
                <p><br>Here, the down arrow key should not prevent you stopping anywhere</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var PP = $.fn.pagepiling;
            function s2() {
                PP.moveSectionDown();
            }

            function s3() {
                PP.moveSectionDown();
            }

            function s4() {
                PP.moveSectionDown();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

And here is the running demo of my code (shout out to Himesh for raising this suggestion to add this in)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0nj7rma/1/)

Comment: seems you are trapping down and right only - and moving to page1 if activesection is 1, page2 if activeSection is 2 ... looks wrong

Comment: Yes it looks wrong - in fact when I initially coded it, I coded it to move to page 1 if activesection is 2, etc. However turns out, when it says activesection it actually refers to the previous section for some reason, therefore when I coded move to page 1 if activesection is 1, it actually stopped the section from proceeding, thats when I said "ah got it" but then I didn't get it because I can't seem to change it when I get pass page 1.

Comment: @Henry hii there might be issue with activeSection this variable and the other thing is that for up arrow key the keyCode is 38 not 39 and for down arrow key is 40 is correct

Comment: Hi Himesh, thanks for your suggestion, I actually want the right and down arrow key, not the up arrow key. Would 39 then be correct for the right arrow key? And also what issue are you talking about with regards to activeSection? Cheers, Henry